# Is there a way to configure Apache and mod_userdir to not use ~

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-userdir

I am using Apache 2.4 on RHEL8 to give users there own web pages. Right now the URL looks like example.com/~username. Is there a way to setup Apache and mod_userdir so that the ~ is not used? I'd like for the URLs to look like example.com/username

Thank you,

Mike

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can roll your own:

```
AliasMatch ^/(user1|...|usern)(/.*|$) /home/$1$2
```

See [AliasMatch](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#aliasmatch). If that doesn't meet your needs, you can do it more flexibly with mod_rewrite.